# Probability that the dot product of two binary vectors is $0$ or $1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two binary vectors $f$ and $r$. Elements of $r$ are drawn from uniform random distribution, while elements of $f$ are drawn from a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$ (so $i^{th}$ element of $f$ is $1$ with probability $p$).  How would I calculate the probability that $f \cdot r \equiv0\text{ mod }2$?

Comment: Q1: what is meant by 'uniform random distribution'? Q2: do you want the probability that the dot product is $0$ or$1$ (title), or the probability that it $f.r\equiv0\text{ mod }2$? I suspect the last, but am not sure so check my edit.

Comment: A1: $r_i$ is 0 or 1 with equal probability.  A2: dot product is $0 \mod{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the $f_{i}r_{i}$ are Bernoulli distributed with parameter
$\alpha:=P\left\{ f_{i}=1\right\} P\left\{ r_{i}=1\right\} =\frac{p}{2}$.

That implies that $f.r=f_{1}r_{1}+\cdots+f_{n}r_{n}$ is binomially distributed
with parameters $\alpha$ and $n$.

This leads to $P\left\{ 2\mid f.r\right\} =\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\alpha^{2k}\left(1-\alpha\right)^{n-2k}$ for $\alpha =\frac{p}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

In dimension $1,$ the probability is obviously $p/2.$ If the probability of $1$ in dimension $n$ is $q,$ the probability in dimension $n+1$ is $q(1-p/2) + (1-q)p/2 = q(1-p) + p/2.$ So, we have a recurrence $q_{n+1} = q_n(1-p) + p/2,$ so $q_n = \frac{p}2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (1-p)^i.$