# Mistake while trying to compute the following probability?

Tags: probability

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $b$ be a non-zero vector in $\{0,1\}^n$. For $a$ uniformly distributed in $\{0,1\}^n$ define $\langle a,b \rangle = \sum_i
>  a_ib_i \mod 2$. Prove that $\Pr[\langle a,b \rangle =
>  0]=\frac{1}{2}$.

For the case where $b$ is random uniform, there's [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591138/probability-that-the-dot-product-of-two-binary-vectors-is-0-or-1) approach. However, here the assumption is that $b$ is some constant vector, which seems to complicate things (at least for me).

I tried the following approach, but ended up with what feels like an unnecessarily complicated term, which led to me think that this may not be the best approach:

Denote by $k$ the number of $1$s in $b$. Then:

$$ \Pr[\sum_i
 a_ib_i = even] = \sum_{l=0}^{k/2} {k \choose 2l}\Pr[a_i=1]^{2l}\Pr[a_i=0]^{k-2l}=\frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{l=0}^{k/2} {k \choose 2l}$$

which leaves me with trying to prove that the last sum is equal to $2^k/2$. Since this seems too complicated for this problem, my questions are:

a. Am I mistaken anywhere?

b. Is there a better approach?

c. Regardless of (b), and assuming I am not mistaken, is there some known value for this sum?

Comment: Apologies - fixed now ($a$ is random uniform)

Comment: Since $b$ is nonzero, there is some $k$ for which $b_k=1$. Consider the term $a_kb_k$ in the sum mod 2.

Comment: @Karl Thanks, so if I understand correctly, you're suggesting to condition on the remainder of the terms? (the value of their sum?)

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted an answer and then deleted it, because I realized that its analysis was identical to the comment of @Karl.

Comment: To the OP, re Karl's comment: given fixed $(b)$, let $r_b$ denote the index of the leftmost non-zero component of $(b)$.  Then, for any $(a) \in \{0,1\}^n$, let $(\overline{a_b})$ denote the partial complement of $(a)$, where the only difference between the two vectors is in their $(r_b)$ component.  Then, their corresponding sums must yield different odd/even parities.  Further, the entire set of random variables $(a) \in \{0,1\}^n$ can be partitioned into the disjoint union of pairs $\{(a), (\overline{a_b})\}$.  In each pairing, the corresponding sums will have different odd/even parities.